# IIS 7 and Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7, windows-authentication

We have IIS 7 running on the Windows 2008 Server which hosts many intranet websites.  We want to use windows authentication for the website and its url will be http://pay

So, I add the C:\InetPub\pay folder and bind it to the IIS7.
Disable the Anonymous Authentication mode.
Enable the Windows Authentication mode.

When I access the website http://pay from the other computer, I got the message that

> Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page
>   using the credentials that you supplied.

So, I go to the Windows Explorer and Add the **Local\IUSR** account and give access to the folder.  But I still got the same error.

Finally, I added **Everyone** account and give access to the folder.  This time, it works and windows authentication is also working well.

What I am afraid is that, does it open the read access to Everyone to the \MyServer\C$\Inetpub\pay folder?  It contains the web.config which contains server and users credential and it would be the big security breach.

How can I achieve to use **Windows Authentication** without giving access to **Everyone** account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you you're looking for is the IIS_IUSRS group which you should give read access to your website folders when using Windows Authentication. The IUSR account you tried would be used in an Anonymous Authentication scenario.

More info on these groups in IIS7 here:
[Understanding Built-In User and Group Accounts in IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis/)